CSS break-after: right is not adding two page breaks
I'm trying to print 2 page reports on the front/back of a piece of paper. Sometimes the data overflows onto a 3rd page. When printing multiple reports this causes the first page after an overflow to print on the back of the piece of paper, and the second to print on the front of the next piece of paper. I'm trying to avoid hiding the overflow.
According to Mozilla Developer Network break-after: right I should be able to use this to print an extra blank page to force the next report to the front side of the paper.

Forces one or two page breaks right after the principal box, whichever will make the next page into a right page. It's the page placed on the right side of the spine of the book or the front side of the page in duplex printing.

I'm not able to get two page breaks in Chrome, Edge, or Firefox.
I'm expecting "Report 2" to be on page 3 and a blank page for page 2. Instead, Report 2 starts on page 2.
I've tried left, recto, verso, break-before, deprecated styles: page-break-after/page-break-before.


.mypage {
  break-after: right;
}
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
<div class="mypage">Report 1</div>
<div class="mypage">Report 2 - I expect this to have a blank page before it.</div>




On the Mozilla documentation for break-after, it says:

page
Forces a page break right after the principal box.

So, you can use break-after: page as shown:


.mypage {
  break-after: page;
}
<div class="mypage">Report 1</div>
<div class="mypage">Report 2 - I expect this to have a blank page before it.</div>




added print buttons to the snippets. break-after: page has the same result as right, but I'm expecting an extra blank page.
